# TYPO3: Custom CE backend permissions

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

I created several content elements, some of them with the help of the "mask" extension.

The issue is that backend users in the "editor" user group are unable to edit custom content elements.

Where can I edit those permissions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the configuration of the backend user group.
2. Open the tab "Access Lists"
3. Add the tables which are needed for inline elements in "Tables (listing)"-section and "Tables (modify)"-section
4. Allow the fields needed in this tables and tt_content (Page Content) in the "Allowed excludefields"-Section
5. Allow the usage of the elements in the "Explicitly allow/deny field values"-section

This should do the job.